# Store glassfish password in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

This is Netbeans 6.9.1 and a Glassfish 3.0.1 server registered as a remote domain.  Somewhere along the line Netbeans stopped storing the Glassfish admin password, and it prompts me on startup.  I actually have quite a few remote domains registered for different test and dev levels so this is very annoying.

How do I change configuration to start storing these passwords again?  I really don't care if they're secured as these are development servers on an isolated network.

After some fiddling I found it's actually not the Netbeans version but the glassfish 3 support.  If I register a glassfish 2.x server then the password setting is available.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the services tab, expand Servers. Right click on the instance in question and view the properties. The password is right there.

Comment: That's where it used to be.  There's no password option there since I went to 6.9.

Comment: My neighbor has 6.9.1 and his works. The password is only gone if it's a local instance.

Comment: Updated the question.  It looks like the password is only gone if it's a glassfish 3.x registration.